# PHPExcel auto size column width

Tags: php, resize, size, phpexcel

I'm trying to auto size the columns of my sheet. 
I'm writing the file and in the end I try to resize all of my columns.

```
// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'test1111111111111111111111')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'test1111111111111')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'test1111111')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'test11111')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'test1')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'test1');

foreach($objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension() as $col) {
    $col->setAutoSize(true);
}
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateColumnWidths();
```

The above code doesn't work. Doesn't change the column size to fit the text

**UPDATE**
The writer I'm using `$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');`

Answer (score 228, accepted):

If a column is set to AutoSize, PHPExcel attempts to calculate the column width based on the calculated value of the column (so on the result of any formulae), and any additional characters added by format masks such as thousand separators.

By default, this is an `estimated` width: a more accurate calculation method is available, based on using GD, which can also handle font style features such as bold and italic; but this is a much bigger overhead, so it is turned off by default. You can enable the more accurate calculation using

```
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
```

However, autosize doesn't apply to all Writer formats... for example CSV. You don't mention what writer you're using.

But you also need to identify the columns to set dimensions:

```
foreach(range('B','G') as $columnID) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension()` expects a column ID.

`$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimensions()` will return an array of all the defined column dimension records; but unless a column dimension record has been explicitly created (perhaps by loading a template, or by manually calling `getColumnDimension()`) then it won't exist (memory saving).

Comment: Thank you so much. It works. It does not calculate the extra spacing created from the bold font, although that's expected (I've read it somewhere). Could you update your answer to include that too?

Comment: If you need that degree of precision with typeface style such as bold or italic, then you need to use PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT, but it is a lot slower

Comment: It's ok I don't care. Although I don't know how to do it. I'm using the 01simple-download-xls.php from the Test folder. Where do I add that line? Sorry for my complete noobness. I've just started to play with it.

Comment: Also, If you don't want to iterate via column letters but indexes instead you can use the static method PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($columnIndex) to get the column letter

Comment: @MarkBaker Is there any method available to do with a single statement so that we can set width of columns given in a list. Currently I am using      $activeSheetObj->getColumnDimension('G')->setWidth(35); the columns in the list may be of any order.

Comment: The only option to provide a list is to loop through an array of column names is as shown in @TodStoychev's answer, iterating over that array

Comment: In 2019 using PhpSpreadsheet you can do this: `Font::setAutoSizeMethod(Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);` with `use PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Shared\Font;`.

Answer (score 66):

If you need to do that on multiple sheets, and multiple columns in each sheet, here is how you can iterate through all of them:

```
// Auto size columns for each worksheet
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {

    $objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex($objPHPExcel->getIndex($worksheet));

    $sheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $cellIterator = $sheet->getRowIterator()->current()->getCellIterator();
    $cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells(true);
    /** @var PHPExcel_Cell $cell */
    foreach ($cellIterator as $cell) {
        $sheet->getColumnDimension($cell->getColumn())->setAutoSize(true);
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the better solution, since it doesn't require a special consideration for columns past Z.

Comment: I can confirm this answer works flawlessly in PhpSpreadSheet as well. Thanks a ton!

Comment: Use `$worksheet->getColumnIterator()` to simplify things here. Refer to my answer

Answer (score 28):

Here a more flexible variant based on @Mark Baker post:

```
foreach (range('A', $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {
        $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()
                ->getColumnDimension($col)
                ->setAutoSize(true);
    }
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: This does only work until Z, because `range('A', 'AB')` will just return one item named 'A'. So using `range()` in this case is NOT a good idea!

Comment: This works though:    for ($i = 'A'; $i != $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn(); $i++) {
    $worksheet->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
  }

Comment: Do not use this. Please see my answer that uses the `$sheet->getColumnIterator()`

Answer (score 21):

Do not use range() it wont work beyond column Z.

Simply use:

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
foreach ($sheet->getColumnIterator() as $column) {
    $sheet->getColumnDimension($column->getColumnIndex())->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Do this after you have written your data so that the column iterator knows how many columns to iterate over.

Answer (score 20):

```
for ($i = 'A'; $i !=  $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn(); $i++) {
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($i)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
}
```

Comment: good answer but should be `$i <= $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestColumn()` otherwise last column doesn't get sized

Answer (score 11):

This is example how to use all columns from worksheet:

```
$sheet = $PHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$cellIterator = $sheet->getRowIterator()->current()->getCellIterator();
$cellIterator->setIterateOnlyExistingCells( true );
/** @var PHPExcel_Cell $cell */
foreach( $cellIterator as $cell ) {
        $sheet->getColumnDimension( $cell->getColumn() )->setAutoSize( true );
}
```

Comment: Please add some context around your answer to explain how it solves the problem

Answer (score 10):

for phpspreadsheet:

```
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet(); // $spreadsheet is instance of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet

foreach (
    range(
         1, 
         Coordinate::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestColumn(1))
    ) as $column
) {
    $sheet
          ->getColumnDimension(Coordinate::stringFromColumnIndex($column))
          ->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Comment: ```foreach (range('A', $sheet->getHighestDataColumn()) as $column) {$sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);}```

Comment: @WesleyAbbenhuis your comment will only work when there are no more than 26 columns. When the highest column is for example: 'AH' the range function will not work properly.

Answer (score 6):

This code snippet will auto size all the columns that contain data in all the sheets. There is no need to use the activeSheet getter and setter.

```
// In my case this line didn't make much of a difference
PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);
// Iterating all the sheets
/** @var PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet */
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getAllSheets() as $sheet) {
    // Iterating through all the columns
    // The after Z column problem is solved by using numeric columns; thanks to the columnIndexFromString method
    for ($col = 0; $col <= PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($sheet->getHighestDataColumn()); $col++) {
        $sheet->getColumnDimensionByColumn($col)->setAutoSize(true);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4):

In case somebody was looking for this.

The resolution below also works on `PHPSpreadsheet`, their new version of PHPExcel.

```
// assuming $spreadsheet is instance of PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Spreadsheet
// assuming $worksheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
foreach(range('A',$worksheet->getHighestColumn()) as $column) {
    $spreadsheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

> Note: `getHighestColumn()` can be replaced with `getHighestDataColumn()` or the last actual column.

What these methods do:

`getHighestColumn($row = null)` - Get highest worksheet column.

`getHighestDataColumn($row = null)` - Get highest worksheet column that contains data.

`getHighestRow($column = null)` - Get highest worksheet row

`getHighestDataRow($column = null)` -  Get highest worksheet row that contains data.

Answer (score 3):

```php
// Auto-size columns for all worksheets
foreach ($objPHPExcel->getWorksheetIterator() as $worksheet) {
    foreach ($worksheet->getColumnIterator() as $column) {
        $worksheet
            ->getColumnDimension($column->getColumnIndex())
            ->setAutoSize(true);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach(range('B','G') as $columnID)
{
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($columnID)->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Come late, but after searching everywhere, I've created a solution that seems to be "the one".

Being known that there is a column iterator on last API versions, but not knowing how to atuoadjust the column object it self, basically I've created a loop to go from real first used column to real last used one.

Here it goes:

```
//Just before saving de Excel document, you do this:

PHPExcel_Shared_Font::setAutoSizeMethod(PHPExcel_Shared_Font::AUTOSIZE_METHOD_EXACT);

//We get the util used space on worksheet. Change getActiveSheet to setActiveSheetIndex(0) to choose the sheet you want to autosize. Iterate thorugh'em if needed.
//We remove all digits from this string, which cames in a form of "A1:G24".
//Exploding via ":" to get a 2 position array being 0 fisrt used column and 1, the last used column.
$cols = explode(":", trim(preg_replace('/\d+/u', '', $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->calculateWorksheetDimension())));

$col = $cols[0]; //first util column with data
$end = ++$cols[1]; //last util column with data +1, to use it inside the WHILE loop. Else, is not going to use last util range column.
while($col != $end){
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(true);

    $col++;
}

//Saving.
$objWriter->save('php://output');
```

Answer (score 2):

If you try to iterate with `for ($col = 2; $col <= 'AC'; ++ $col){...}`, or with `foreach(range('A','AC') as $col) {...}` it will work for columns from A to Z, but it fails pass the Z (Ex. iterate between 'A' to 'AC').

In order to iterate pass 'Z', you need to convert the column to integer, increment, compare, and get it as string again:

```
$MAX_COL = $sheet->getHighestDataColumn();
$MAX_COL_INDEX = PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString($MAX_COL);
    for($index=0 ; $index <= $MAX_COL_INDEX ; $index++){
    $col = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($index);

    // do something, like set the column width...
    $sheet->getColumnDimension($col)->setAutoSize(TRUE);
}
```

With this, you easy iterate pass the 'Z' column and set autosize to every column.

Answer (score 1):

you also need to identify the columns to set dimensions:

```
foreach (range('A', $phpExcelObject->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()) as $col) {
$phpExcelObject
        ->getActiveSheet()
        ->getColumnDimension($col)
        ->setAutoSize(true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$col = 'A';
while(true){
    $tempCol = $col++;
    $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension($tempCol)->setAutoSize(true);
    if($tempCol == $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getHighestDataColumn()){
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please reformat your answer and think about this: A **good answer** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.

Answer (score 0):

For Spreedsheet + PHP 7, you must write instead of `PHPExcel_Cell::columnIndexFromString`, `\PhpOffice\PhpSpreadsheet\Cell::columnIndexFromString`. And at the loop is a mistake, there you must `<` not work with `<=`. Otherwise, he takes a column too much into the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, i solved like this.

```
$Sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
$lABC1 = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');
$lABC2 = array('A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S','T','U','V','W','X','Y','Z');

for($I = 0; $I < count($lABC1); $I++):
  $Sheet->getColumnDimension($lABC1[$I])->setAutoSize(true);
  for($J = 0; $J < 6; $J++){
    $Sheet->getColumnDimension($lABC2[$J].$lABC1[$I])->setAutoSize(true);
  }
endfor;
```