# Auto size Excel column width

Tags: php, excel, laravel

I'm using Laravel [Excel plugin](https://github.com/Maatwebsite/Laravel-Excel) and have a problem with column widths. See the picture below, you can see the mistake:

[image]

Here is the correct view:

[image]

I tried `$sheet->setAutoSize('true');` but it is not working.

How can I auto size column to the maximum content width of any cell in that column?

Answer (score 9):

```
$sheet->getColumnDimension($column)->setAutoSize(true) ;
```

Duplicate of [PHPExcel auto size column width](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761897/phpexcel-auto-size-column-width)