# PHPExcel unexpected formatted number

Tags: php, phpexcel, currency-formatting

I want to convert a number in a USD format. What I tried is

```
$xl = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
$xl->getStyle("$col$row")->getNumberFormat()->setFormatCode('$0.00');
```

But in the export, the value is displayed as `####` for large numbers. Ex. if the amount is `11121` then in the export it is displaying as `$11121.00` which is expected, but for the number `155555` it is displaying as `#######` in the export output. I have an idea about `PHPExcel_Cell_DataType::TYPE_STRING`. But I want the currency in USD format and at the end of the file, I am generating the sum of all rows (sum of all price).

I also tried`PHPExcel_Style_NumberFormat::FORMAT_CURRENCY_USD` but no luck.

Comment: isn't it that the column is smaller than what it takes to fit the number in? Have you tried to make the column wider?

Comment: Autosize the Cell width, see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/16762003/715105

Comment: @LelioFaieta yes it worked. It was because of the column width issue. Thanks for that.

Comment: @JustBaron I am using the same code for autosize, but it is not working for the cost columns.