# Converting an html table to excel with SpreadSheet but displaying-hiding the data inside the excel file cause of the small default cells

Tags: php, jquery, phpexcel, spreadsheet, phpspreadsheet

Everything works great my html table can succesfully converte to excel. But here is the issue. Code:

```
$spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();
$sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
$sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'Projects First Year');
$sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'Grades');

$sheet->setCellValue('A2', 'PHP Project 2020');
$sheet->setCellValue('B2', $_SESSION['phpScore']);
```

As you can see from the example above i am saying that place the  `'Projects First Year'` in the cell A1, place the `Grades` to the cell B1, place the `'PHP Project 2020'` to the cell B2 etc. Here is the **PROBLEM**. When i download my html table that has been converted to excel, i open the excel file with the data that i passed and the cells Hide the `'Projects First Year'` because the cell of the excel it is by default small and my data `'Projects First Year'` is bigger the result is this

---

[image].

---

Anyone knows how to fix this inside the code? Thank you . The rest of the code

```
$filename = 'sample-'.time().'.xlsx';
// Redirect output to a client's web browser (Xlsx)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');
// If you're serving to IE 9, then the following may be needed
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1');

// If you're serving to IE over SSL, then the following may be needed
header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: ' . gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s') . ' GMT'); // always modified
header('Cache-Control: cache, must-revalidate'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public'); // HTTP/1.

$writer = IOFactory::createWriter($spreadsheet, 'Xlsx');
$writer->save('php://output');
```

Comment: Not a php person, but is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16761897/phpexcel-auto-size-column-width) helpful?

Comment: these answers are old.. and i think that the lib is changed.. i can't find any of these `functions()` that they are saying

Answer (score 1):

You can set the with of a cell with see [documentation here](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/recipes/#setting-a-columns-width).

```
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(12);
```

with autosize you start a more or less good automatic callculation.

```
$sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(true);
```